# Trying to get the run capacitors right for my rotary phase converter. Getting weird results

Tags: three-phase

I constructed a rotary phase converter from a 5 HP motor.  The converter converts 220 single phase to 240 3 phase.  Well, it is supposed to.  I am getting some very odd results that I am wondering if someone can help explain.

I wired up the circuit exactly how is done below:

[image]

I used a ~420 uF starting capacitor and it works just fine starting up, but the legs are out of phase when it is running.  The weird part is, even if I remove the run cap completely, it is STILL out of phase.  I had 3 capapaciotors on hand, a 15uF, 30uF, and 50uF, so I did some experiments and I am getting confusing results.  Here are the voltages between the wires:

[image]

There doesn't appear to be a capacitance value I can choose to get all of the legs in phase.  Furthermore, why is it that the legs are out of phase without a run capacitor?  Is the back EMF from the potential relay causing an unintentional phase shift?

Comment: I thought a rotary phase converter was essentially a motor driving a generator. You seem to be trying to use a single-phase induction motor as a phase converter by itself. Am I just ignorant, or is what you are trying to do kind of sketchy/impossible? At best, I would think this arrangement would be VERY load dependent.

Comment: I may be using the wrong terminology, but this kind of thing is done very frequently by machinists wanting to run 3 phase machines on single phase power (which is the reason I want to do it too).  From what I can find, many many people have claimed to have done this successfully and have had it work for years.  That doesn't mean it isn't load dependent though.  I am sure the legs go out of phase a bit when under heavy load, but apparently it isn't enough to cause obvious harm.

Comment: I was thinking that it may only work properly when the load is connected. The load, being a three-phase motor, would be reactive, too, and may affect the balance. Anyway, I will bow out since I can't help. Watching with interest.

Comment: Maybe just clarify one point. The 5 HP motor. Is it a three-phase motor, or a capacitor run, capacitor start single phase motor as shown in the schematic? And if the latter, where are you taking your three-phase power from? The videos I found on youtube all showed a three phase motor being used to create three phase power.

Comment: Yes the motor is a 3 phase motor.  Two of the phases come from L1 and L2, and the third one comes from one of these lines but is phase shifted by the starting cap. I will be taking 3 phase power from the motor itself after it has been started, as once it is running, it generates the third leg. (At least according to my knowledge)

Comment: Well, the motor you have shown in your schematic only has two windings. Basically, your schematic looks like a single phase motor with a starting winding. Maybe you should update your schematic.

Comment: Huh you know what, I have been working on the assumption that those windings were in a delta arrangement in a 3 phase motor (this isn't my schematic, I found it on the internet).  For some reason I just thought they were omitting the third winding.  Well that might explain something! Lol.  

But it should work regardless.  All this is is just introducing a phase shifted signal from one of the legs.  This signal, plus the two other legs go into the motor and make it run.

Comment: Well, nobody else is chiming in. We do have some motor experts here, but I am not one of them. Based on my perusal of various youtube videos, I don't think you need any run capacitor. Just a start capacitor. If you use a pilot motor to get your three-phase motor started, you don't even need the start capacitor. Once your three-phase motor is spinning on single-phase power, connect the three-phase load. The current and voltage should be reasonably balanced, but may not be perfect.

Comment: The weird part is, even if I put NO run capacitor, the voltages are out of phase by a lot.  You can see in the top left corner of the note book pic I posted that I get line voltages of 98, 95 and 122.5.  Am I just using a bad motor for this?

Comment: When you take that measurement, is it with load or without? In other words, you are using one motor as a phase converter because you need three phase power to drive a load. What is that load, and is it attached when you measure? If not, try attaching it and re-measuring. But I also don't understand how you can be applying 220 to a winding and only getting 120. So, something strange about your data.

Comment: Well your comment made me go look at my wiring.  I mixed up the neutral wire with one of the legs.  Now I am getting 240 V and the motor runs awesome! Still the same issue though with the phasing. I think it is just the motor I am using for my idler.  With the machine on as the load, I am getting 240, 240 and 214 for the three pairs of legs.  I hope this is good enough to not ruin the motor.

Comment: Yeah. That may be normal for this type of arrangement. I just don't know. But if the motor appears to be running smoothly, I would be tempted to let it be. Of course that is easy for me to say, since I have nothing to lose. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This sort of idling-motor rotary phase convertor produces 3 output terminals from two input terminals.  Let's call the two inputs L1 and L2 which can be +120v and -120v (180 degrees out of phase) or 120v and neutral.  From your notes it seems like you might be using 120v and neutral.  However I've usually seen this used to construct 240 or 208 volt 3phase from a 240 volt circuit.

The three outputs let's call them A, B, and C.  A is equal to L1 and is connected to one terminal on the idler motor.  Likewise B is equal to L2 and is connected to another terminal on the idler motor. And C is the third terminal on the idler motor.  If you spin up the idler motor and connect power, it will continue to run on single phase power.  Another option is to momentarily connect a start capacitor across A-C or B-C to get the motor turning, then remove the start capacitor.

When the motor is idling like this, the C leg will be producing voltage induced by the magnetic fields in the rotating motor.

Now, consider two ways of measuring voltages:  1) you can measure voltages at A, B, and C to ground, or 2) you can measure voltages between the phase A-B, B-C, A-C.  I'll call the former the phase voltages and the latter the phase-to-phase voltages.

The phase voltages will be 
A = L1 = 120v AC RMS
B = L2 = 120v AC RMS
C will be something a bit less than 240v AC RMS.  Typical value will be ~85--90% of twice the L1 and L2 voltages or something on the order of 210 volts.
If you look at them on a 3 channel oscilloscope, you will see L1 and L2 are 180 degrees out of phase (as they were before you attached your motor; after all you are tiny compared to the power grid).  And C will be pretty close to in the middle between A and B but double the amplitude.  So C is about 90 degrees off of both A and B.

The phase-to-phase voltages are what happens when you take differences between these phase voltage sine waves.
A-B will be 240v AC RMS
B-C will be ~230v AC RMS
A-C will be ~230v AC RMS
So that looks like 3-phase.  And it is 3-phase, just not at 120 degree separations but rather at 90, 180, and 270 degrees.

That's almost all there is to it.  Attach another 3-phase induction motor to ABC and it will turn and produce torque and run your milling machine or lathe or grinder, etc.  But, since the power isn't equal voltage, 120-degree separated 3-phase, the motor won't work quite as well as the specifications on the motor dataplate say.  You need to derate the motor a bit to compensate for 2 things: for the bad phase angles and for the unequal phase voltages.

You can compensate somewhat for the unequal phase voltages by adding run capacitors across A-C and B-C.  These will conduct additional current to the C-leg and help boost that weak leg back up to nominal voltage.  If you choose the caps just right, you can get it perfect, but those values will depend on the load, so how big a cutter you are spinning on your milling machine and how deep and fast you are cutting.  It isn't practical to jiggle the capacitors around for every different cut, and the derating isn't that important if the motor is lightly loaded, so usually you choose the run capacitor sizes to suit a heavy load.

Compensating the 90, 180, 270 phase angles towards 120, 240, 360 is harder and I've never seen it done.  But in principle you could add an LC circuit in one of the input legs, like between L2 and B. You would tune that LC to get a 120 degree relationship between A and B, but again it would depend on load.  And you'll need a huge inductor, about the size of your idler + load motors.  So before you go this way, you'd build a motor-generator phase convertor or just buy a VFD which synthesizes the output 3-phase from rectified input power.

Answer (score 0):

James at Clough42 has a nice discussion which clears up a lot of the confusion about phase converters. Briefly, yes this is a VERY common approach; it's well tested and works.

It does produce real 3 phase power (at 120 separation) not funny three phase (at 0 180 270.) The issue there is the reference used. One needs a 3 phase motor/generator about 1.5-2x the expected load (5hp can drive a total of 3hp.) A delta connected 3 phase motor is needed to allow neutral reference (that is, 120 as well as 3 phase 220 from the same system) but a wye motor works fine for just 3 phase only.

To build your own, see the thread at Practical Machinist on phase converters; look up the Fitch design. American Rotary is a well regarded supplier of these systems, including provide your own motor panels.